# Шахматная доска php. консольное приложение

Tags: php, ооп, консоль, redis

Прошу помочь понять следующее задание на PHP:

> Существует шахматная доска определенного размера. На эту доску можно
>   добавлять различные фигуры (ладьи/туры/пешки). Добавленную фигуру
>   можно перемещать или удалять.
>   В любой момент времени состояние доски
>   можно сохранить в или загрузить из хранилища: в redis или файл. При
>   реализации стоит учесть, что видов фигур может быть больше, чем
>   описано выше; также что виды хранилищ могут меняться.
>   Кроме того,
>   добавьте возможность вызова пользовательского кода в момент, когда на
>   доску добавляется фигура определенного типа/фигура любого типа
>   (например, выводить текстовое сообщение при добавлении любой фигуры /
>   при добавлении только ладьи). Задача не подразумевает использование
>   фреймворков. Реализация пользовательского интерфейса не требуется
>   (приложение должно быть консольным).

Я не могу представить, как можно реализовать все это на консоли. Как пользователь должен вводить данные для добавления/перемещения/удаления фигуры. Еще говорится, что видов фигур может быть больше, значит надо реализовать добавление новой фигуры? если да, то тоже как? Также мне не понятен момент с "Кроме того, добавьте возможность вызова пользовательского кода в момент, когда на доску добавляется фигура". Что здесь понимается под пользовательским кодом?
Буду благодарен за любые советы! 
Ниже то, как я реализовал все это на данный момент:

```
<?php

class Chess
{
    public $board_array;
    public $config;
    public $onAddFigure;

    function __construct() 
    {
        $this->board_array = array(
            '1'=>array('a'=>' ','b'=>' ','c'=>' ','d'=>' ','e'=>' ','f'=>' ','g'=>' ','h'=>' ',),           
            '2'=>array('a'=>' ','b'=>' ','c'=>' ','d'=>' ','e'=>' ','f'=>' ','g'=>' ','h'=>' ',),           
            '3'=>array('a'=>' ','b'=>' ','c'=>' ','d'=>' ','e'=>' ','f'=>' ','g'=>' ','h'=>' ',),           
            '4'=>array('a'=>' ','b'=>' ','c'=>' ','d'=>' ','e'=>' ','f'=>' ','g'=>' ','h'=>' ',),       
            '5'=>array('a'=>' ','b'=>' ','c'=>' ','d'=>' ','e'=>' ','f'=>' ','g'=>' ','h'=>' ',),           
            '6'=>array('a'=>' ','b'=>' ','c'=>' ','d'=>' ','e'=>' ','f'=>' ','g'=>' ','h'=>' ',),           
            '7'=>array('a'=>' ','b'=>' ','c'=>' ','d'=>' ','e'=>' ','f'=>' ','g'=>' ','h'=>' ',),           
            '8'=>array('a'=>' ','b'=>' ','c'=>' ','d'=>' ','e'=>' ','f'=>' ','g'=>' ','h'=>' ',)            
            );
        $this->config = [
              'figures' => [
                    'пешка' => 'o',
                    'ладья' => 'x',
                 ],
              'symbols' => ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'],
              'keys' => ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'],
            ];
   }

   public function startGame()
   {
        print('> Выберите действие:'.PHP_EOL);
        print('1. Добавить фигуру'.PHP_EOL);
        print('2. Удалить фигуру'.PHP_EOL);
        print('3. Переместить фигуру'.PHP_EOL);
        print('4. Добавить новую фигуру'.PHP_EOL);
        print('5. Сохранить доску'.PHP_EOL);        
        print('6. Загрузить доску'.PHP_EOL);        
        $handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
        $line = fgets($handle);
        $line = trim($line);
        switch ($line) {
            case '1':
                $this->addFigure();
                break;
            case '2':
                $this->removeFigure();
                break;
            case '3':
                $this->moveFigure();
                break;
            case '4':
                $this->addNewFigure();
                break;  
            case '5':
                $this->saveBoard();
                break;      
            case '6':
                $this->loadBoard();
                break;      
            default:
                print('Выберите одно из 6-х действий'.PHP_EOL);
                $this->startGame();
                break;
        }   
   }

   public function showBoard()
   {
        print('    |a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|');
        print(PHP_EOL);
        $counter = 0;;
        foreach ($this->board_array as $key => $value) {
            $counter++;
            print('   '.$counter.'|');
            foreach ($value as $symbol => $val) {
                print($val.'|');
            }
            print(PHP_EOL);
        }
        print(PHP_EOL);
   }

   public function addNewFigure()
   {
        print('Добавление новой фигуры:'.PHP_EOL.'Введите название для новой фигуры:'.PHP_EOL);
        $figure_name = $this->getFigureName();
        $validate_fname = $this->validateFigureName($figure_name);
        if ($validate_fname)
        {
            print('Введите обозначение для новой фигуры:'.PHP_EOL);
            $figure_icon = $this->getFigureIcon();
            $validate_ficon = $this->validateFigureIcon($figure_icon);
            if ($validate_ficon)
            {
                $this->config['figures'] += array($figure_name => $figure_icon);
                print('Новая фигура "'.$figure_name.'" успешно добавлена!'.PHP_EOL);
                $this->showBoard();
                $this->startGame();
            }
            else
            {
                print('Не введено обозначение для фигуры!'.PHP_EOL);
                $this->addNewFigure();
            }
        }
        else $this->addNewFigure();
   }

   public function addFigure()
   {
        print('Добавление фигуры'.PHP_EOL);
        $figure_icon = $this->chooseFigure();
        $isset_figure = $this->issetFigure($figure_icon);
        if ($isset_figure)
        {   
            print('Выберите позицию для добавления, например d5:'.PHP_EOL);
            $position = $this->choosePosition();
            $validate_position = $this->validatePosition($position);
            if ($validate_position)
            {
                $isempty_position = $this->isemptyPosition($position);
                if ($isempty_position)
                {
                    if(is_callable($this->onAddFigure)){
                        $this->onAddFigure();
                    }
                    $symbol = $position[0];
                    $key = $position[1];
                    $this->board_array[$key][$symbol] = $figure_icon;
                    print('Фигура успешно добавлена'.PHP_EOL);
                    $this->showBoard();
                    $this->startGame();
                }
                else
                {
                    print('Указанная позиция не свободна!'.PHP_EOL);
                    $this->addFigure();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print('Не корректно введена позиция!'.PHP_EOL);
                $this->addFigure();
            }
        }
        else $this->addFigure();
   }

   public function removeFigure()
   {
        print('Удаление фигуры'.PHP_EOL.'Выберите позицию для удаления фигуры:'.PHP_EOL);   
        $position = $this->choosePosition();
        $validate_position = $this->validatePosition($position);
        if ($validate_position)
        {
            $isempty_position = $this->isemptyPosition($position);
            if (!$isempty_position)
            {
                $symbol = $position[0];
                $key = $position[1];
                $this->board_array[$key][$symbol] = ' ';
                print('Фигура успешно удалена'.PHP_EOL);
                $this->showBoard();
                $this->startGame();
            }
            else
            {
                print('На указанной позиции нет никакой фигуры!'.PHP_EOL);
                $this->removeFigure();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print('Не корректно введена позиция!'.PHP_EOL);
            $this->removeFigure();
        }
   }

   public function moveFigure()
   {
        print('Перемещение фигуры'.PHP_EOL.'Выберите позицию откуда переместить:'.PHP_EOL); 
        $first_position = $this->choosePosition();
        $validate_position = $this->validatePosition($first_position);
        if ($validate_position)
        {
            $isempty_position = $this->isemptyPosition($first_position);
            if (!$isempty_position)
            {
                print('Выберите позицию куда переместить:'.PHP_EOL);
                $second_position = $this->choosePosition();
                $validate_position = $this->validatePosition($second_position);
                if ($validate_position)
                {
                    $isempty_position = $this->isemptyPosition($second_position);
                    if ($isempty_position)
                    {
                        $f_pos_sym = $first_position[0];
                        $f_pos_key = $first_position[1];
                        $s_pos_sym = $second_position[0];
                        $s_pos_key = $second_position[1];
                        $this->board_array[$s_pos_key][$s_pos_sym] = $this->board_array[$f_pos_key][$f_pos_sym];
                        $this->board_array[$f_pos_key][$f_pos_sym] = ' ';
                        print('Фигура успешно перемещена!'.PHP_EOL);
                        $this->showBoard();
                        $this->startGame();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print('Указанная позиция занята другой фигурой!'.PHP_EOL);
                        $this->moveFigure();
                    }
                }   
                else
                {
                    print('Не корректно введена позиция!'.PHP_EOL);
                    $this->moveFigure();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print('На указанной позиции нет никакой фигуры!'.PHP_EOL);
                $this->moveFigure();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print('Не корректно введена позиция!'.PHP_EOL);
            $this->moveFigure();
        }
   }

   public function saveBoard()
   {
        file_put_contents("board.json", json_encode($this->board_array));
        print('Текущий вид доски сохранен!'.PHP_EOL);
        $this->showBoard();
        $this->startGame();
   }

   public function loadBoard()
   {
        $this->board_array = json_decode(file_get_contents("board.json"), true);
        //print('Текущий вид доски сохранен!'.PHP_EOL);
        $this->showBoard();
        $this->startGame();
   }

   public function getFigureName()
   {
        $handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
        $figure_name = fgets($handle);
        $figure_name = trim($figure_name);
        return $figure_name;
   }

   public function getFigureIcon()
   {
        $handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
        $figure_icon = fgets($handle);
        $figure_icon = trim($figure_icon);
        return $figure_icon;
   }

   public function validateFigureName($figure_name)
   {
        $result = false;
        if (strlen($figure_name) > 0) $result = true;
        return $result;
   }

   public function validateFigureIcon($figure_icon)
   {
        $result = false;
        if (strlen($figure_icon) > 0) $result = true;
        return $result;
   }

   public function choosePosition()
   {    
        $handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
        $position = fgets($handle);
        $position = trim($position);
        return $position;
   }

   public function chooseFigure()
   {
        print('Выберите фигуру из списка: '.PHP_EOL);
        foreach ($this->config['figures'] as $key => $value) {
            print($key.': '.$value.PHP_EOL);
        }
        $handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
        $figure_icon = fgets($handle);
        $figure_icon = trim($figure_icon);
        return $figure_icon;
   }

   public function issetFigure($figure_icon)
   {
        $result = false;
        foreach ($this->config['figures'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($figure_icon == $value)
            {
                $result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $result;
   }

   public function validatePosition($position)
   {
        $result = false;
        if (strlen($position) == 2)
        {
            $position_symbol = $position[0];
            $position_key = $position[1];
            if (in_array($position_symbol, $this->config['symbols']) and in_array($position_key, $this->config['keys']))
            {
                $result = true;
            }
        }
        return $result;
   }

   public function isemptyPosition($position)
   {
        $result = false;
        $key = $position[1];
        $symbol = $position[0];
        if ($this->board_array[$key][$symbol] == ' ') $result = true;
        return $result;
   }    

}

$game = new Chess();
$game->onAddFigure = function(){ 
     print("обработчик добавления фигуры".PHP_EOL);
};
$game->showBoard();
$game->startGame();
```

Comment: вряд ли ведь это учебное задание? тестовое на собеседовании?

Comment: @teran, Да, тестовое

Comment: @teran, получается сама доска не вырисовывается в консоли?

Comment: я бы нарисовал, и выводил перед меню действий (там еще, кстати, должно быть меню вида Начать/Сохранить/Загрузить/Выйти).

Comment: дополнил ответ по этому поводу

Comment: Я конечно все понимаю... Но зачем такие вещи городить в консоли? Для проверки скилла, линуксоиды так развлекаются на серваках, где нет графической оболочки? Прошу, объясните мне.

Comment: @teran, Если вам не составит труда, посмотрите пожалуйста мою реализацию данного задания. Единственно, мне не удалось реализовать вызов пользовательского кода, получаю ошибку "Call to undefined method Chess::onAddFigure()". Я не знаток в ООП, может подскажете как правильно выполнять данную задачу? Код разместил выше.

Comment: Тоже сейчас это тестовое делаю. Только еще юнит тестами надо покрыть.
У вас какой-то GOD object. Я разобью на несколько смысловых классов (Поле, игра, фигуры) со своими функциями. Также не все функции должны быть публичными. Ну и конструкция из большого числа вложенных if и else смотрится монструозно. Можно было сделать отдельный класс валидатор. https://github.com/volokolamskspb/GameChess

Comment: потом как сделаете, скиньте ссылочку, поучусь как надо было делать

Comment: А вот моё видение этого задания https://github.com/Hunternnm/chess
На правоту не претендую, быстро делал

Comment: https://github.com/volokolamskspb/GameChess

Вот моя реализация. Ушло дня 3. 

Для создания и движения фигур взяла образец отсюда: 
[Demo classes for moving chess pieces](https://gist.github.com/VirtuosiMedia/3688742)

Мне пока не ответили, так что не знаю, правильна ли реализация. Да и юнит тесты написала в последний момент и первый раз их пишу. Так бы переписала структуру под них. Но до ума доводить и делать полноценную игру там еще недели 2 понадобится.

Comment: @Baurzhan и Julia, для обсуждения и дискуссий есть [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com). Здесь только вопросы и ответы. Данный ресурс не ссылкообменник.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> На эту доску можно добавлять различные фигуры (ладьи/туры/пешки). Добавленную фигуру можно перемещать или удалять

Это значит, что ваше консольное приложение обрабатывает некоторый цикл ввода команд от пользователя. И на каждой итерации предлагаем ему добавить, удалить или переместить фигуру. Что то вроде:

```
> Выберите действие:
  1. Добавить фигуру
  2. Удалить фигуру
  3. Переместить фигуру 
  4. Главное меню
```

После того, как пользователь ввел, например, `1`, должна запустить функция добавления, которая в свою очередь должна запросить какую фигуру добавить,и на какую позицию, предварительно проверив, что позиция свободна.

> Еще говорится что видов фигур может быть больше, значит надо реализовать добавление новой фигуры?

Скорее всего здесь подразумевается, что ваш скрипт должен иметь некоторый конфиг, в котором будут описаны типы фигур, и то как они отображаются на доске. Что-то вроде

```
$config = [
      'figures' => [
            'pawn' => ['ico' => 'o', 'title' => "пешка"],
            'rook' => ['ico' => 'X', 'title' => "ладья"],
         ],
   ];
```

Соответственно этото перечень должен запрашиваться при добавлении фигуры, и из этого конфига должны браться символы для отрисовки поля (если таковая вообще нужна).

> Также мне не понятен момент с "Кроме того, добавьте возможность вызова пользовательского кода в момент, когда на доску добавляется фигура

Подразумевается, что вы разрабатываете некую библиотеку, которую будет использовать другой пользователь. Вот допустим он инициализирует вашу доску:

```
$game = new GameField(['size' => 12]);
```

и ваш класс должен генерировать события добавления фигур, и позволять добавлять обработчики для этих событий. а-ля

```
$game->onAddFigure = function($item){ 
     print "пользовательский обработчик добавления фигуры";
});
```

а где то в вашем коде он будет вызываться, при наличии (как-то так примерно)

```
public function addFigure($f){
    ....
    if(is_callable($this->onAddFigure)){
        ($(this)->onAddFigure)($f);
    }   
    ....
}
```

> В любой момент времени состояние доски можно сохранить в или загрузить из хранилища: в redis или файл. также что виды хранилищ могут меняться

Тут говорится о том, что вам необходимо описать интерфейс для сохранения данных, и пару его реализаций. одна в файл, другая в redis. Класс игры же будет будет создавать экземпляр его реализации и производить с ним нужные дейстия

```
interface IGameLoader  {
    public function save($state);
    public function load();       
}

class JsonLoader implements IGameLoader(){
     public function save($state){
        .....
        file_put_contents("...", json_encode($state));
     } 

     public function load(){
     }
}
```

ну а класс игры должен также иметь методы load,save и передавать управление нужной реализации внутри.

```
$game->save('json', "./data.json");
```

зы: по поводу вывода игрового поля

Если допустим у нас игровое поле выглядит как двумерный массив, где в значениях будет тип фигуры

```
  private $field = []; // изначально, но в конструкторе класса надо сделать NxN
```

то вывод поля на эркран можно сделать банально так

```
protected function printField(){
    for($row = 0; $row < $this->size; $row++){
         $rtxt = implode(' | ', array_map(function($cell){
                          if(!$cell) return ' ';
                          return $this->config['figures'][$cell]['ico'];
                    }, $this->field[$row]));

         print "$rtxt\n";
    }
}
```